# Unable to find sources for uncommon specific heat

Tags: temperature

I'm calculating the energy, temperature, and gas volume outputs of gunpowder. To solve this I need to find the specific heat of Potassium sulfate (K2SO4) and Potassium carbonate (K2CO3). If anyone can refer me to any directory that can list the values for these it would be very helpful.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For potassium sulfate see [here](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C7778805&Units=SI&Mask=FFF).

For potassium carbonate see [here](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C584087&Mask=2).

Generally, search in the [NIST Chemistry WebBook](http://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/) and when you find the compound of interest, either click on "gas phase thermochemistry data" or "condensed phase thermochemistry data" as appropriate.